# Least value of algebraic expression

Tags: inequality

> Least value of $x^{2017}+y^{2017}+z^{2017}-2017xyz$, where $x,y,z\geq 0$

Try: I am trying to solve it using the arithmetic-geometric inequality

$$\frac{x^{2017}+y^{2017}+z^{2017}}{3}\geq (xyz)^{\frac{2017}{3}}$$

Could some help me to solve it , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the AM-GM
$$x^{2017}+y^{2017}+z^{2017}+\underbrace{1+1+\cdots+1}_{2014 \text{ terms}} \geqslant 2017xyz$$
$$\implies x^{2017}+y^{2017}+z^{2017}-2017xyz \geqslant -2014$$
and note equality is possible in the AM-GM when $x=y=z=1$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Using your result from AM-GM,
$$x^{2017}+y^{2017}+z^{2017}-2017xyz\ge3(xyz)^{\frac{2017}3}-2017xyz\,.$$
Now set $w=xyz$ and minimize $3w^{\frac{2017}3}-2017w$ on the RHS.